# How do I infer the return types of an object of functions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
const actions = {
  setF1: (a: number) => ({
    type: 'a',
    a
  }),
  setF2: (b: string) => ({
    type: 'b',
    b
  })
};

type ActionTypes = ?

export default reducer = (state = {}, action: ActionTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'a':
      console.log(`${action.a} is a number`);
      return {
        ...state,
        a
      }
    case 'b':
      console.log(`${action.b} is a string`);
      return {
        ...state,
        b
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The goal is every time I add a function to the `actions` object, the reducer would automatically infer the action return type in the `switch` statement. I'm trying to avoid the scenario where I need to do something like `action: Action1 | Action2 | Action3`.

Comment: You should use an `enum` instead of string literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that is to use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) in your definition of `actions` so that the compiler doesn't widen your `type` property to `string`, the rest is relatively simple.

```js
const actions = {
  setF1: (a: number) => ({
    type: 'a' as const,
    a
  }),
  setF2: (b: string) => ({
    type: 'b' as const,
    b
  })
};

type ActionKeys = keyof typeof actions; // "setF1" | "setF2"
type ActionTypes = ReturnType<typeof actions[ActionKeys]> // { type: "a", a: number } | { type: "b", b: string }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=58&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhsKBLcEYF4YG8CwAoGGCAUygDEBGALhgAo4awBXAWwCNiAnASgwD46uAoRhQAngAdiNAORwZ8NKEhQANPhHwNMAL7d1wkuQBMNWmxrROSMAHNe6AbSGbxU2WwVwlqNdsJs2nr4OgDc+PhuxDAAgogoYADSxGJomADWKSAAZqKSxDnw8ajheFGxxWAAKvlpMABKpEyc1fkAPFGFCMioANpxPUkpEAC6fBF4ytAwnMQAJkzAXBh00HBQ0ZhYOqpFgzQDCTVSEA4CLkQA7khQwAAWdN0JAHRRvBeawN7RcjJU-poRFMQAAbYjPEEgWy0AAGABIsE9wM84DoYEg0HAYMx2FwYdxSoDAWxZnB0oTAV8SDAZJ5-sIiYRgWCIVDYQikWBnmw0Rj4EQoNY7PiKYyYCTiGSKToQqEgA)